# Setting permissions from profiles files and permissionsets files

Tags: permissions

We refreshed our pro sandbox and now we need to reassign the permissions to objects from a backup zip file copy of our sandbox which we got using force.com eclipse (yes, we got the Profiles and Permisionsets folders and their contents). Some objects are missing their respective permissions and we only have the those files. How can we reassing -programmatically if possible- the needed permissions?

Comment: have you loaded the backup into eclipse and tried deploying? you can also use the force.com migration toolkit (ant library) to deploy a zip file to a target environment

Comment: We do not want to overwrite the permissions inherited from Production and the backed profiles files had very different permissions to Production. So, we need to find those fields with no permissions and  see if they have a counterpart in the zipped profile file and re-assign them to those fields.

Comment: yep, that's going to be hard, if i were in your shoes, i'd consider just doing it via the setup menu. doing this programmatically is likely possible, but it'll probably be more effort than its worth. tools i've used for similar things in the past (ruby for processing xml) and ant for deploying